SP Online - Installing an app dynamically
I'm pretty newbie on SharePoint, so I apologize if I don't use correct terms or I'm not too clear in the request, I'm trying to do the best.
I'm working on a .Net core project that creates sites dynamically in a SP Online tenant, and have to install an app on them.
The app is available in the AppCatalog and if installed manually, after few seconds everything is ok.
But if installed by code, the app appears opaque in the site contents with the installing message, and after a while goes timeout with "The operation took too long" generic error.
I'm using an authentication by certificate, and the Site.FullControll.All is granted (the same configured in the app manifest).
Below the code:
public void SPWebAppInstall(ClientContext siteContext)
{
    var appMgr = new AppManager(siteContext);
    var cApp = appMgr.GetAvailable().Where(a => a.Title == <myAppName>).FirstOrDefault();
    if(cApp != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if(cApp.InstalledVersion == null)
                 appMgr.Install(cApp);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Could not add the following app: {0}.", cApp.Title));
        }
    }
}

The code does not throws any exceptions, and the appMgr.Install returns true.
Does anyone had the same issue? How to resolve it?
Thanks in advance

Hi Could you please InstallAsync instead of Install. Try the below code.
AppManager manager = new AppManager(context);
      if (manager.Deploy(appId, true))
      {
          if (manager.GetAvailable(appId) != null)
          {
              try
              {
                  Task installTask = Task.Run(async () => await manager.InstallAsync(appId));
                  installTask.Wait();
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  log.Info("Exception Caught – Mostly because the App is already installed. Skipping Install. Message – " + ex.InnerException.Message);
              }
          }
      }

AppId is the App GUID here.

Thanks for your advice, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.
What type of authentication did you use?
I think it's an authentication problem: trying with PnP cmdlets on PowerShell, if connecting with user/pwd it works fine too, but not with certificate.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1290782/not-able-to-install-deploy-app-in-sharepoint-onlin
This could be something related to the permission. Have you tried installing the same app with PnP PowerShell?

I hope you are using same as like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread

Yes, I've already done those steps.
As I told before, I'm not very familiar with SharePoint, but is possible that the problem is the authentication mode?
It seems that it works only through delegated permission, and not with the application one

Can you try this code?
public void SPWebAppInstall(ClientContext siteContext, string myAppName)
{
    var appMgr = new AppManager(siteContext);
    var cApp = appMgr.GetAvailable().Where(a => a.Title == myAppName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (cApp != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cApp.InstalledVersion == null)
            {
                appMgr.Install(cApp); // Install the app
                Console.WriteLine("App installation started.");

                // Poll for installation status
                bool isInstalled = false;
                int maxAttempts = 10; // Limit the attempts to avoid infinite loop
                int attempts = 0;
                while (!isInstalled && attempts < maxAttempts)
                {
                    attempts++;
                    Thread.Sleep(30000); // Wait 30 seconds before checking status again

                    // Refresh app instance to check the updated status
                    var installedApp = appMgr.GetAvailable().Where(a => a.Title == myAppName).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (installedApp != null && installedApp.InstalledVersion != null)
                    {
                        isInstalled = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("App installation completed.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("App still installing. Retrying...");
                    }
                }

                if (!isInstalled)
                {
                    throw new Exception("App installation timed out.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Could not add the following app: {cApp.Title}. Error: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Note:

As we know SharePoint Online has throttling limits for automated
processes. Try adding some delay between multiple site creations and
app installations if done in bulk.

